# R- How to rearrange rows in a data frame with a foreign key from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to rearrange rows in a data frame in R.

I have two data frames which are in different order and both do have a ID which identifies the tipples. 
Now I would like to reorder data frame 1 (ID 1) so that it is in the same order like data frame 2 (ID2).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post your code in order to help you. Members of stackoverflow does not provide ready to use solutions but help to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column of ascending integers in data frame 2 to encode the ordering. Then merge that column to data frame 1 and sort on it.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  col1 = c('a', 'b', 'c')
)

df2 <- tibble(
  id = c(3, 1, 2),
  col2 = c('c', 'a', 'b')
)

df2$ordering <- sequence(nrow(df2))

df1_ordered <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'id') %>%
  arrange(ordering)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` to match the ID's and then reorder `df1` based on it. Using @Chris' data

```
df1[match(df2$id, df1$id),]

#     id col1 
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     3 c    
#2     1 a    
#3     2 b
```